# Poincare section for the duffing Oscillator

Tags: computational-physics, oscillators, differential-equations, software, anharmonic-oscillators

I have used the 4th Order Runge-Kutta method in order to estimate the values in which the Duffing Oscillator is chaotic. According to Wikipedia, the Duffing Oscillator is chaotic for values of $\alpha$ =1, $\beta$ = 5, $\delta$ = 0.02, $\gamma$= 8 and $\omega$ = 0.5.
Equation of the Duffing Oscillator

$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \delta \frac{dx}{dt} +\alpha x + \beta x^3 = \gamma \cos (\omega t)$
Splitting it to systems of differential equations, I will have:

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = v$

$\frac{dv}{dt} = \gamma \cos (\omega t) - \delta v - \alpha x - \beta x^3$

I had tried plotting the Poincare section of $x_n$ against $x_{n+1}$ with limited successes as I did not get a chaotic plot. Here is what that I had tried:

```
def time_series(t0, tn, steps,x0,v0):
    dt = (tn-t0)/steps # the distance between each steps
    xn = [x0]
    vn = [v0]
    for i in range(steps):
        #my logic is that I could use the new values of t,x,v 
        curr = estimate(t0+i*dt, t0 + (i+1)*dt,xn[-1],vn[-1]) 
        #the estimate function does the work on estimating the value of the integral
        xn.append(curr[0]) # the estimate function returns value x and v
        vn.append(curr[1])
        
        #print(start+(i+1)*dt)
    xn1 = xn[1:] # this is so that the 2nd to last value will be xn+1
    xn = xn[:-1] #the values here would be from 1st to 2nd last
    # it would map xn to xn+1
    #plots the graph using a scatter plot
    plt.scatter(t,xn,c="r")
    plt.show()
time_series(1,1.8,30,1,1)  # a test case
```

I am still quite confused regarding how a Poincare plot should be like, so would be glad if anyone would explain it to me.
Below is my code for the estimate function (just for reference if anyone needs it)
It is just the 4th order Runge Kutta Method.

````
a = 1
b = 5
d = 0.02
g = 8 
w = 0.5
steps = 101
# inital conditions x = 1 when t =1, v = 1, when t=1
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def estimate(t0,t1,v_value,x_value):
    t = np.linspace(t0,t1,steps)
    # start at t=0 
    h = t[1] - t[0] 
    xn = np.zeros(steps)
    xn[0] = x_value
    vn = np.zeros(steps)
    vn[0] = v_value
    for n in range(1,steps):
        k1 = vn[n-1]
        l1 = g * np.cos(w * t[n-1]) - d * vn[n-1] - a * xn[n-1] - b * xn[n-1] **3
        k2 = vn[n-1] + h*k1/2
        l2 = g * np.cos(w * (t[n-1] + h/2)) - d * (vn[n-1] + h*k1/2) - a * (xn[n-1] + h*l1/2) - b * (xn[n-1] + h*l1/2)**3

        k3 = vn[n-1] + h*k2/2
        l3 = g * np.cos(w * (t[n-1] + h/2)) - d * (vn[n-1] + h*k2/2) - a * (xn[n-1] + h*l2/2) - b * (xn[n-1] + h*l2/2)**3

        k4 = vn[n-1] + h*k3
        l4 = g * np.cos(w * (t[n-1] + h)) - d * (vn[n-1] + h*k3) - a * (xn[n-1] + h*l3) - b * (xn[n-1] + h*l3)**3
        xn[n] = xn[n-1] + h/6 * (k1 + 2* k2 + 2 * k3+ k4)
        vn[n] = vn[n-1] + h/6 * (l1 + 2* l2 + 2* l3 + l4)
    return xn[-1],vn[n-1]
 ```
````

Comment: Also note that there is the [Scientific Computing Stack Exchange](https://www.scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?